# angularjs loop that show in decrement order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop

how to run a loop in angular that start from 4 and run down to 1 check status value is = define value says alert

```
var total = 4;

for (var i = total; i >= 1; i--) {
  if (total[i] = 1) {
    alert("Reached");
  }
}
```

Please suggest and elaborate about angular loop as well

Comment: I suggest you master (vanilla) Javascript syntax and semantics before attempting to go into AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

First  `total` is not an array so using `total[i]` doesn't make any sense.

You are assing value instead of checking equility

```
 if(total[i] = 1){
```

This should be `==` or `===` instead of `=`

Try like this

var total = 4;

```
for (var i = total; i >= 1; i--) {
  if (i == 1) {
    alert("Reached");
  }
}
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/qbfvv5Lo/)**</kbd>

Comment: better if demo would be created with button when one button enter it says 4 in again says 3 when it comes at 1 says reached

Comment: sorry to disappoint you .But my intension wasn't to make cool UI where you can play . my intension was to pin point you that where you were wrong.

Comment: @Priya this isn't a code factory. If you want a demo first provide a far better explanation of what you are trying to do and provide your own starting point demo for others to modify. It doesn't even sound like a loop is what you need. Expecting others to put more work into an answer than you put into a question is not right